# Haskell list within a list within a list

Tags: list, haskell

I am learning Haskell and I have a problem where if given a list of a list of a list of Strings I have to find the total number of Strings in the entire initial list. My though process was to convert the entire initial list into a one dimensional list and get the length, however I can seem to figure it out.

What I have so far:

```
type Word = String
type Line = [Word]
type Page = [Line]
type Doc = [Page]
numWords :: Doc -> Line -> Word -> Int
```

I need to find the number of Words and I'm not sure if this is even the best way to go about this type of problem, but I am at a loss for ideas.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a simple problem.

If we have a look at the types, it becomes easy:

```
type Word = String
type Line = [String]
type Page = [[String]]
type Doc  = [[[String]]]
```

It's not too difficult to get the length of a `Line`:

```
lenLine x = length x
```

The `Page` is just the sum of all the inner lengths:

```
lenPage xs = sum $ map lenLine xs
```

And we can use the same kind of pattern for `Doc`:

```
lenDoc xs = sum $ map lenPage xs
```

As for your final function , just use all the others:

```
numWords :: Doc -> Page -> Line -> Int
numWords dc pg ln = lenDoc dc + lenPage pg + lenLine ln
```

Remember that a type synonym doesn't mean that the type is actually different; you can use the same functions.

Comment: Thank you so much! The data type stuff is very confusing for me as I'm coming from Java. It seems very different.

Comment: @Jon Don't worry about it - it grows on you :)

Comment: Indeed it does grow on you. :) After using Haskell for a while, you'll find Java more and more unwieldy.

Comment: @Jon keep in mind that having numWords take a document and a page and a line might be triple-counting some lines depending on what you pass it. The simplest way is to *just* use the lenDoc function AJ gave, unless you have some specific need to do something else.